# Would it be by US law a discrimination to limit a job offer by IQ?

Tags: workplace

I am not sure whether there have been cases already in US.

Would it be illegal to say in a job offer they require people from a certain IQ level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What types of "discrimination" are illegal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4143/what-types-of-discrimination-are-illegal)

Comment: not sure, and this question is more specific

Comment: You should explain how the other question doesn't suffice as an answer. You question being "more specific" doesn't mean that the question hasn't already been answered: the answer to your Q is *included in* the answer to the general question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IQ level is not a protected class and so using it to discriminate between job applicants is not illegal per se.

However - in the U.S., studies have shown that self-identified blacks score around 15 points lower than self-identified whites, on average. If your use of IQ to discriminate between applicants reflected this disparity - and did not represent a bona fide occupational qualification (unlikely) - then your use of IQ for this purpose could easily be construed as illegal discrimination based on race.

Comment: For posterity. Here (https://mobile.nytimes.com/1999/09/09/nyregion/metro-news-briefs-connecticut-judge-rules-that-police-can-bar-high-iq-scores.html) is an article about a case where it was found that an employer may choose not to hire someone based on IQ.